# Custom field group on page

Tags: custom-field

I have what I hope is an easy question to answer, even if google has failed to provide me any solution.

Our main webmaster has set up custom field groups which we use with our custom post types for our webpage. Now I want to add a separate page, not using our custom post type, but a "pure" page and I want to use our custom field groups to on this page.

Is that at all possible?

When I tried to expand the screen options and to activate custom fields I do not have the option to add the already existing groups.

Hope you can help me out as I'm unable to contact the webmaster at the moment.

Edit: we are using WordPress 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Registering custom fields group might have been limited to the custom post type. Check the limit so that I should appear everywhere.

Comment: Where would this check box be? We are using  WordPress 4.6.1 if it matters.

Comment: This might have been hard coded or might have been done with plugin like Advance Custom Fields.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the big pushes in the right direction! I checked the plugins and it's indeed Advance Custom Fields. I'll see if I can figure something out from knowing that. In the worst case I will just have to wait for the main admin.

Comment: Check for the options and you will get it.